# How to convert double value to two byte array in c#

Tags: c#

I am developing a windows forms application. I have a double value 1.5.That value I need to convert into a two byte array. But when I am converting using BitConverter.GetBytes, getting 8 bytes of data. Please refer my code below.

```
double d = 1.5;
 byte[] array = BitConverter.GetBytes(d);
```

Comment: what will be output? **array[0] = ? array[1] = ?**

Comment: You can't store a full double or float in 2 bytes, but if you have a specific range/precision in mind (for example always 2 digits of which one is a decimal) you may be able to.

Comment: You should clarify why you expect a double to be convertible to 2 bytes? or in other words, what two bytes do you expect for a given double? or How will those two bytes be used? Without this information, it is unclear what you are asking, and given current information, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Double` is **8** byte value, so if you have an *arbitrary* `double` there's no hope for you; however, if you have some *restrictions*, e.g. the value is in the `[0..100]` range and has at most `2` digits after the decimal point, you can encode it:

```
  // presuming source in [0..100] with at most 2 digit after decimal point
  double source = 1.5;

  // short is 2 byte value
  short encoded = (short) (source * 100 + 0.5);

  byte[] array = BitConvertor.GetBytes(encoded);

  // decode back to double
  double decoded = encoded / 100.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

A double is a 64 bit value that just so happens to be 8 bytes. There's nothing that can be done about this.

Comment: If he wants his result in two byte array, may not he convert his value?

Comment: Wanting "the result in 2 byte array" is not more meaningful then wanting the result in an ice cream scoop.

Comment: Any other data type to store 2 byte float value(positive only) .

Comment: @sowjanya attaluri: `float` is a 4 byte value (`double` is in fact a kind of *doubled* `float`)

Answer (score 1):

A `double` is 8 bytes in length, so unless you want a specific sub-array out of the 8 you're getting *(you probably don't)*, then this is the wrong way to go about it.

You can cast your variable to a single-precision `float`. That will of course lose some precision, but you will get 4 bytes instead of 8.

If this is still unacceptable, you need to have an implementation of a [half-precision float](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Half-precision_floating-point_format), which sadly doesn't come out-of-the-box with .NET.

I found an implementation here:
http://sourceforge.net/p/csharp-half/code/HEAD/tree/System.Half

You can use it like this:

```
var half = (Half)yourDouble;
var bytes = Half.GetBytes(half); // 2 bytes
```